# How to make css columns into primeng?

Tags: css, angular8, primeng

I'm working with primeng. I have this code to display my data.

My Html:

```
 <p-table #table [columns]="cols" [value]="list" [paginator]="true"  responsive="false">
            <!---------------- Header of datatable event ------------------>
            <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
                <colgroup>
                    <col *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngStyle]="{'width' : col.width}">
                </colgroup>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                        {{ col.header | translate}}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <!---------------- Body of datatable event ------------------>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                    <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngStyle]="{'width': col.width }">
                        <div *ngIf="col.field !== 'idOption'">
                            {{rowData[col.field]}}
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="col.field === 'idOption'">
                            {{rowData[col.field]}}
                            <span *ngIf="rowData.activeOpt">
                                <em class="fa fa-lg fa-check-circle" style="color: green; padding-left: 50%"></em>
                            </span>
                            <span *ngIf="!rowData.activeOpt">
                                <em class="fa fa-lg fa-check-circle" style="color: red; padding-left: 40%"></em>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
```

I get this result:

[image]

I want that the green fa-check-circle will be in the same line, really i spent many time without any solution. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why icons are not aligned is because icon is placed just after the text & the length of text will vary based on the `Garantie` values.

So in order to keep our icons aligned irrespective of the text length, we can fix the alignment to always right [float:right] (not after the text ends).

Please change your active & inactive icon code line with below.

Active icon (green):

```
<em class="fa fa-lg fa-check-circle" style="color: green; float:right"></em>
```

Inactive icon (red):

```
<em class="fa fa-lg fa-check-circle" style="color: red; float:right"></em>
```

[image: View After Implementation]